# Custom Toolbar Views not centered

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

When using `ActionBarDrawerToggle` with my custom `Toolbar`, the `TextView`s in the `Toolbar` are no longer centered.

[image: Check image]

`main_layout.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`toolbar.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNavTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorBackgroundBlack"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNavDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorBackgroundBlack"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I tried setting the `contentInsetStart` and other attributes on the `Toolbar`, but nothing changed.

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? You neglected to mention it.

Comment: space benhind hamburger icon. i need to display the custom toolbar in full width

Comment: The `Toolbar` is full-width. That's what the hamburger icon is in; the `Toolbar`.

Comment: then why the "Home" text is not in the center?

Comment: Because the `RelativeLayout` starts after the icon, which is actually an `ImageButton` itself. Your `TextView`s are centered in the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: i am not agree with your conclusion. Is it mentioned anywhere in android forums or anywhere?

Comment: Don't agree with what, exactly? Your image shows pretty much what I'm saying. I'm not sure which part you don't agree with. Anyhoo, I don't know if it's documented anywhere, but I've been through `Toolbar`'s source code enough to know how it works.

Comment: hamburger icon is and toolbar are separate.

Comment: i need the "Home" toolbar title in the center of toolbar

Comment: OK, how are you creating the hamburger icon?

Comment: using ActionBarDrawerToggle

Comment: OK, then the hamburger icon and the `Toolbar` are not separate. The icon is an `ImageButton` that is the first child `View` in the `Toolbar`, and is pushing the start of the `RelativeLayout` to the right, which is why the `TextView`s aren't centered with respect to the `Toolbar`. Do you really want the toggle to be blue, and the rest black? Or did you just set those backgrounds black for testing?

Comment: those backgrounds are for testing. I need to move the text inside the toolbar at center of toolbar. but because of that hamburger I am not able to do that.

Comment: OK, then everything blue, yeah? Gimme a minute, and I'll fix your layout.

Comment: Oh, hi, there. I was just trying to add the details we discussed in comments, to make this easier to find when people search for similar issues. Of course, it's your post. You can have it as you like it. Cheers!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is that `ActionBarDrawerToggle`'s icon is set as the navigation button on the `Toolbar`. This button is a special child of `Toolbar` that will take precedence in the layout. Any other child `View`s added to the `Toolbar` will be allotted only the space remaining after that `ImageButton` is placed. This is pushing the left side of your `RelativeLayout` to the right, so the `TextView`s you have centered in that will not be centered with respect to the `Toolbar` itself.

Fortunately, `Toolbar`'s `LayoutParams` has a gravity property that we can utilize to center the `LinearLayout` and its `TextView`s directly in the `Toolbar`, without having to wrap them in another `ViewGroup`. We can also set the gravity appropriately on your `ImageView` to similarly align that to the right side.

In this example, we apply that center gravity by setting the `LinearLayout`'s `layout_gravity` to `center`. Be sure to also change the `layout_width` values to `wrap_content`, or you'll be in the same boat as before. The `ImageView` here has its `layout_gravity` set to `right|center_vertical`, replacing those `layout_*` attributes specific to `RelativeLayout`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNavTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNavDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

---

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I fixed with the `android:contentInset`

Try with this code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:contentInsetEnd="50dp"
                android:contentInsetLeft="50dp"
                android:contentInsetRight="50dp"
                android:contentInsetStart="50dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:contentInsetEnd="50dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="50dp"
                app:contentInsetRight="50dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="50dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/app_name_short"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```