# Adding menu-item to custom action bar displaces text

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to create a custom action bar for my app. I want the app-name to appear in the center of the the action bar, on the left side I want to have a menu item, and on the right side I want to have a custom button. The problem is when I add the menu item, the app-name is displaced from the center towards right side as if something is pushing it there, how can I fix this issue, such that the app name will always remain in the center?
Thank you!

Here is my action-bar layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/customButton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my menu-item xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.rashish.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/back_action"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/back"
        app:showAsAction="always"
       />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:enabled="false"
        />

</menu>
```

This is how I set the custom action bar:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite)));
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_layout);
```

This is how I add the menu items:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.mMenu = menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, mMenu);

        MenuItem itemBack = mMenu.findItem(R.id.back_action);
        MenuItem appIconItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.app_icon);


        itemBack.setVisible(false);
        appIconItem.setVisible(true);


        return true;
    }
```

> UPDTAE

The new layout file using Mike M. suggested solution. The button is placed correctly however the text with the title is still displaced towards the button.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="click me"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

> UPDATE

This the screenshot of my result.
[image]

This is the result that I get, it seems to me that the App name is pushed towards the button rather then being centered, and it seems that the toolbar layout isn't full width.

Comment: It's probably easier if you use a `Toolbar`, set it as the support `ActionBar`, then do something similar to what is shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41962801), putting the `TextView` and `Button` directly in the `Toolbar`, and setting the appropriate `layout_gravity` attributes on them.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @MikeM. however it didn't solve my problem, my text is still appears to be shifted.

Comment: You need to have the `<TextView>` directly in the `<Toolbar>`, and set its `layout_gravity="center"`. No `<RelativeLayout>`, or anything else wrapping it. Then, unless the `Toolbar` itself isn't full width and centered, the `TextView` should always be centered, no matter if there's a menu, or navigation button, or what have you. Double check all that, and if it's still not working, we can have a look at your current setup.

Comment: I just want to clarify, I should set the width of the toolbar to be either a hard coded number or wrap_content?

Comment: No, I meant that as long as your `Toolbar` is "normal" - i.e., `match_parent` width; it goes all the way across the top of the `Activity` - then the `TextView` should be centered, if setup correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still having problems with that, can you please look at my layout file?

Comment: Yeah, sure thing.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with the new layout file.

Comment: This is what I get when I put your setup into an empty AppCompat project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmLnM.png. The magenta line is the center, and the title is centered right over that. Is that not what you're getting? Can you take a screenshot of your results?

Comment: Yes, I will post my screenshot to show my result, however what happens when you add a menu item to the left side of the toolbar, is the text still remains centered?

Comment: How exactly are you adding a menu to the left side? I thought that was a typo in your question. Menus generally appear on the `end`, which is the right side in left-to-right layouts.

Comment: My layout is RTL so it appears on the left side.

Comment: OK, then, if I set RTL, my screenshot would just be a mirror image of that one. What's the custom button on the right side, and how are you adding it? It sounds like that might be your issue.

Comment: I posted the way I add the menu items in my question. The XML code and the JAVA code. It appears under the action_bar_layout.

Comment: Oh, yeah, hang on. I glossed over your menu, and thought those items were disabled/hidden. Gimme a second to rerun this.

Comment: OK, sorry about that. I was confusing things, 'cause I didn't read you code as closely as I should've. Anyhoo, here's the screenshot with the menu in RTL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ70l.png. I used the default launcher icon, 'cause I don't have your `logo` drawable, but the title is still centered.

Comment: I added my screenshot to the question can you take a look?

Comment: Got it. Let's move this to chat, before a mod has a conniption.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164907/discussion-between-mike-m-and-keselme